# Change English Windows 2003 to Chinese

Tags: windows-server-2003

I want to change a Windows 2003 32-bit server so that all the interfaces/menus/dialogs show Chinese text. I tried setting the Regional and Language Options to set the Standard Formats to Chinese. I tried setting the location to China, and also added the IME input settings for Chinese. The OS is still showing English menus, even after rebooting.

On Windows 7 I think this is accomplished by installing a language pack through Windows Updates. I'm unable to find the equivalent language pack for Windows 2003 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924852) explains how language and regional settings are applied in Server 2003, and includes details on how to change them.  [This MSDN blog post](http://www.siao2.com/2004/12/11/279998.aspx) is a little more detailed, and includes screenshots, which may be of use.

In order to change the menu languages, however, you will need to install a [Multilingual User Interface Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688178.aspx), which are unfortunately only available for download through volume licensing, MSDN licensing and OEM agreements with Microsoft.  So if you don't have it installed, you might not be able to get it, in which case you'd have to either live with English menus, or install a Chinese copy of Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Yeah, the first thing I tried was using the Regional and Language Options to set the Standard Formats to Chinese. I changed the location to China, and also added the IME input settings for Chinese. The OS is still showing English menus, even after rebooting.

Comment: @briankb Updated my answer.  You might be outta luck, sorry.

Comment: I can't find MUI in MSDN at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I have a number of the MUI CDs from MSDN at work.  I'll see if they have a part number on them (when I get into the office), but given the age of the product, I wouldn't be too surprised if it never got put up as a digital download and are one of those products you have to get on *shudder* physical media.